# How does an empty for loop make my code work?

Tags: c

So I have the code below written in C and it is supposed read a number from a file and then print the largest number you can make with its digits. so basically digits sorting.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

FILE* inFile;

int main()
{
    long n;
    int a[10];

    inFile = fopen("a.in", "r");

    fscanf(inFile, "%ld", &n);

    int m = 0;

    while(n != 0) {
        a[m] = n%10;
        m++;
        n = n / 10;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < m - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < m; j++) {
            int aux;
            if(a[i] < a[j]) {
                aux = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = aux;
            }
        }
    }

    long n2;
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
        n2 = n2* 10 + a[i];
    }

    printf("\n%ld", n2);
    fclose(inFile);

    return 0;
}
```

But for some reason, it did not want to print result that I wanted and it only printed random numbers for each run. I wanted to make a for loop that prints the digits to check if they are correct in the array and magically it worked. and then, out of curiosity, I made the for loop be empty just to see if it still works, and it does....

Can someone explain what an empty for loop does to save my code? XD

the file should contain:

432432

and the expected output is 443322

Comment: could you please add an example of a file content your program expects?

Comment: [Edit] and show your actual code. The code in the question does not compile. Also provide a simple example if the a.in file and show the expected and the actual output of your program. Read this: [ask]

Comment: Anyway, you never put anything in the `n2` variable,  Look closely at the line `numarMare = n2* 10 + a[i];` and the lines around. It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: I added the expected output and the file content. Also I renamed numarMare to n2. Tried to do that before posting but somehow that one got away

Comment: Your newly edited code never initializes `n2`.

Comment: Try running it with "0" as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty loop does not make your code work.
It only causes a different of many possible outcomes of Undefined Behaviour.
One of those is "it seems to work", which you observe.
Another one, which you seem to have observed before is "it seems to have a logical error".
Neither has any meaning as long as you have Undefined Behaviour, look it up, or, for fun "nasal demons".

You have Undefined Behaviour because you are using an uninitialised variable, `n2`.